# ng-model throws error when input type number is string AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the value of the `ng-model` is `"24" (string)` instead of `24 (number)`, on an `input[type="number"]` it throws following error:

> Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngModel/numfmt?p0=24

I tried to set the input as follow:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="HouseNumber"
       ng-model="Number(HouseNumber)" />
```

However, this throws also an error:

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngModel/nonassign

How can I let `AngularJS` ignore this error / strict binding, or convert this automaticly to a `number` in the `ng-model`?

I cannot set the input to `type="text"`.

---

**Just to visualize the error**

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
  // I cannot simply change this in the actual code to $scope.number = 24;
  $scope.number = "24";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="number" ng-model="number"/>
</div>
```

**When changing the input type to `type="text"` it works** 
I can't do this however in the actual code, as the input should stay a number.

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
  // I cannot simply change this in the actual code to $scope.number = 24;
  $scope.number = "24";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="text" ng-model="number"/>
</div>
```

Comment: try using  `ng-model="HouseNumber" ng-change="Number(HouseNumber)"` and in your controller: `$scope.Number = (x) => {return Number(x);}`

Comment: you cannot set the `ng-model` on a function

Comment: Why don't you post your running code with error? That will probably  help us to find the exact problem.

Comment: I added a fiddle, which reproduces the exact same error.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey No that is not possible, as Angular says not to use functions as a model. See this link: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngModel/nonassign

Comment: @red I tested it, yeah you are right, so I made a directive instead, check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the initialisation of a variable and cast a string, then change the input. (*If the mountain will not come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain*)

You would need to write a **directive** that overrides input functionalities. I have adopted this little feature, that you can change however you like for your app:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.x = "24";
});

app.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, $el, attrs, ngModel) {
      if ($el[0].type === "number") {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          return Number(value);
        });
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          return parseFloat(value, 10);
        });
      }

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="x">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Not much experience on Angular, but wouldn't a simple `parseInt` be more than enough to do what you ask for?

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
  // I cannot simply change this in the actual code to $scope.number = 24;
  $scope.number = parseInt("24", 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="number" ng-model="number"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

input[type=number] requires a numeric value, and angular decorators for the field would type check it. You have to cast the value to a number to use the input[type=number] field.